# Anglo-Catholics and the Ordinariate

Tags: anglicanism

How many Anglo-Catholics (I.e. members of the Traditional Anglican Communion or derived churches) are there in the world today and how many have joined the Ordinariate set up by the Roman Catholic Church?

Comment: There is one fellow who visits this site who actually is a brave member of the Ordinariate. But I think the numbers are still relatively small

Comment: Thank you for the introduction @PeterTurner! I'll see what I can find out about numbers (but it's not easy, or there would have been no need for the question)

Comment: You may mean the [Traditional Anglican Communion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_Anglican_Communion). The Anglican Communion is the worldwide body of *all* Anglicans.

Answer (score 3):

Numbers in the three current Personal Ordinariates are the easy part of the question:

- UK (Our Lady of Walsingham): about 90 clergy and 1300 lay people;
- US (Chair of S Peter): about 100 clergy and 1400 lay people;
- Australia (Our Lady of the Southern Cross): single figures.

The Australian Ordinariate was only set up a month ago. It appears not even to have a website of its own yet.

As DJClayworth has written, gauging the number of Anglo-Catholics is not really possible. The TAC doesn't have an enormous membership in England, for example.

As far as the Church of England is concerned, which has fairly well-defined metrics such as membership of [Forward in Faith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_in_Faith) or the adoption of various [Resolutions](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukcm/1993/2/section/3), even there those metrics double-count some and leave out others. And while one might count the 100-strong congregation of an "Anglo-Catholic" church as Anglo-Catholics, only 14 adults (and seven children) from mine joined the Ordinariate.

Comment: Do you have references for the memberships? I'm interested because I couldn't find them.

Comment: @DJClayworth http://www.ordinariate.org.uk/page.aspx?pid=405 (2011 figures; more have joined since then). http://usordinariate.org/faq.html (although I may have misunderstood and those figures are *intending* members rather than *current actual* members).

Answer (score 2):

This [FaithWorld article](http://blogs.reuters.com/faithworld/2010/01/14/traditional-anglican-bloc-eyeing-union-with-rome-is-far-flung-group/) says that the higher estimates of the membership of the Traditional Anglican Communion as about 400,000 worldwide. This compares with about 85 million Anglicans worldwide. However the TAC does not represent all Anglo-Catholics. Anglo-Catholicism is not a well-defined group, but it is certainly much larger than 400,000.

Wikipedia has [a good article on the Anglican Ordinariates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglican_Ordinariate), which includes a list of churches and groups which are part of an Ordinariate. Most of these groups number a few thousand at most. Even members of the TAC groups sometimes refuse to join an Ordinariate.